# Can one apply for a visa outside their home country?

Tags: visas, paris, bosnia, tunisian-citizens

My friend is from Tunisia and wants to visit Bosnia-Herzegovina over the summer.
There are no Bosnian Embassies or Consulates in all of Tunisia, the nearest is in Libya. She is visiting Paris soon so I wanted to know is it possible for her:

to apply/get a visa for Bosnia in the **Embassy of Bosnia-Herzegovina in Paris**?

She is not a resident of France, just a visitor.

Comment: A glance at the Paris embassy's web page does not look promising, but the only way to know for certain is to ask at the embassy in Paris and/or the one in Tripoli.

Comment: @phoog What disturbs me most about the embassy web site is that it appears to have been compromised and is displaying links to potentially malicious web sites.

Comment: @MichaelHampton good catch, I did not notice that.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't appear that you can apply for a visa for Bosnia-Herzegovina in Paris if you're in the country on a short stay.

One of the requirements for obtaining a visa from this embassy is:

> - une preuve de légalité de son séjour en France (validité de 90 jours supérieur à la date d’expiration du visa),
>
> proof of the legality of your stay in France (valid for 90 days longer than the visa expiry date)

The embassies in a couple of other countries I checked (UK and US) had similar requirements.

You will need to apply for the visa from the embassy or consulate serving your residence. I was not able to find an *official* web site for the Bosnian embassy in Libya, but it appears that that would be the correct embassy to apply at.

The embassy in Paris *may* be willing to waive this requirement, on the grounds that there is no embassy serving your country, and travel to the embassy in Libya would be too dangerous. You should contact the embassy in Paris to ask about this possibility. Interestingly, citizens of neighboring Algeria are directed to apply at the Bosnian embassy in Paris! So this is not entirely out of the question.

---

There is a possible bright side, though: If you have a valid *multiple entry* Schengen visa, you can [use it to enter Bosnia and Herzegovina](http://www.bhembassy.no/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=17&Itemid=28&lang=en) for a maximum stay of 15 days, if you travel there from a Schengen country.

Comment: Three months later, and that embassy website is _still_ compromised. That's a little disturbing.

Comment: Nine months on, and the embassy web site is completely gone without a trace. Lovely.